# HTML form with php variable

Tags: php, html, forms

```
<?php $tripid = $_GET['trip']; ?>
<form name="requestform" method=post action="?page=feedback&trip=<?php $tripid ?>" >
    <p>
        <label>Please Provide a Feedback: </label>
        <textarea rows=3 cols=75 title="Feedback" name="feedback"></textarea>
    </p>
    <center><input type=submit value="Submit"></center>
</form>
```

When I submit and get redirected to the next page, URL only gets "?page=feedback&trip="
the $tripid doesn't GET into the URL.

Comment: You are not outputting `$tripid` -- you forgot to use `echo` (or some variant). i.e. `<?php $tripid ?>` does not output anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do

```
<?php echo $tripid ?>.
```

It is also possible to set php short tag using the `short_open_tag` php.ini configuration directive.  I often use the php function `http_build_query` to generate a query string.  Also, if not using `http_build_query` then do not forget to `urlencode` the `$tripid` variable.